# How can I tell when Docker Desktop has started in a PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I want to write a PowerShell script that will create a number of running docker containers on boot of the machine. The problem I'm running into is that despite the `com.docker.service` service running, the backend for Docker Desktop (I presume WSL2) is still getting ready.

I can manually recreate this behaviour by running `docker version` or similar when the system is starting. It will show:

```
error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

However after a couple of minutes (once the backend has come up) then the command will start working:

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.22
 Version:           20.10.11
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.10
 Git commit:        dea9396
 Built:             Thu Nov 18 00:42:51 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
```

How can I reliably wait for Docker Desktop to be ready before trying to start containers? I suspect the solution might be waiting for the pipe file or similar rather than a service.

Comment: You could check the return code of a docker command in a loop (with a sleep) until you get a 0 back

Comment: @M_dk I'm far more familiar with Bash, am I right to assume that windows commands have exit codes like Bash commands do?

Comment: Yeah, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200325/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script